# Combine even and odd lists using split() and append() in R

Tags: r, list, split, append

Consider the following MWE:

```
x <- rnorm(100) # generate values
k <- 4 # number of groups

y <- split(x, 1:k) # split values into k groups
y

# combine even and odd lists
for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  for (j in 1:length(y)) {
    if ((i %% 2 == 1) && (j %% 2 == 0)) {
     res <- append(y[[i]], y[[j]])
    }
  }
}

res
```

The above works except

(1) only elements from lists 3 and 4 in `y` are included because values are being overwritten during the second pass of the `for` loop.

(2) I would like to modify the above loop so that `res` returns a list of lists (in the same way they are returned by `split()`. That is `res` should contain one list containing `y[[1]]` and `y[[2]]`, along with a second list containing `y[[3]]` and `y[[4]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for:

```
split(y, gl(2,2))
```

If you do not know the length of `y` before hand use:

```
split(y, gl(length(y)/2,2))
```

If you want only odds and only evens:

```
split(y, 1:2)
```